# Excel Idle time-out with a timed message box warning of save and closing in a set time

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the coding that will enable me to close and save an inactive excel worksheet when not being used for a period of time (15 secs in the example below) however what I would like to do is before the worksheet saves and closes I would like a Warning message box on the screen to indicate that this will save and close in X-minutes Options Save or Continue/cancel?

```
Enter into "This Workbook"

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Call TimeStop
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call TimeSetting
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Call TimeStop
Call TimeSetting
End Sub


Enter into "module":

Dim CloseTime As Date
Dim WKB As String
Sub TimeSetting()
WKB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
CloseTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:15")
On Error Resume Next
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=CloseTime, _
Procedure:="SavedAndClose", Schedule:=True
End Sub
Sub TimeStop()
On Error Resume Next
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=CloseTime, _
Procedure:="SavedAndClose", Schedule:=False
End Sub
Sub SavedAndClose()
Workbooks(WKB).Close Savechanges:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't show a messagebox for this, since it will block your code.  Your best bet for this would be a custom userform which get shown non-modally.

Answer (score 0):

I use messagebox, and it works :)
Last sub....

```
`Sub TimeSetting()
  CloseTime = Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")
  On Error Resume Next
  Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=CloseTime, _
  Procedure:="Message", Schedule:=True
 End Sub
 Sub TimeStop()
  On Error Resume Next
  Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=CloseTime, _
  Procedure:="Message", Schedule:=False
 End Sub
 Sub Message()
   Result = MsgBox("blalbabla", vbYesNo + vbExclamation)
   If Result = vbYes Then
   MsgBox "Leave me alone :)"
   Else
   MsgBox "Save and Close"
   Workbooks(WKB).Close Savechanges:=True
   End If
  End Sub`
```